# Postfix disable address rewrite

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix server that I am using as an outbound SMTP gateway for a mail server.  The postfix server has a name such as smtp.domain1.com.

Now, I have users on my mail server that are trying to send messages to poorly formatted addresses, such as to user@domin.  My postfix server is rewriting the address as user@domain.domain1.com.

How can I configure postfix to not rewrite the address and bounce the message if the address is not complete?  I believe this can be done with the append_at_myorigin paramter, but the Postifx documentation says that this feature must not be turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to stop postfix from rewriting addresses on any "local" mail, use

```
local_header_rewrite_clients =
```

"local" in this context means mail sent from the machine itself, and any clients that connect from IP addresses in "$mynetworks", which would likely be the case if this is an internal->external SMTP gateway.

The default setting is

```
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces
```

which causes postfix to rewrite addresses for mail when the client IP matches $inet_interfaces.

There are a bunch of other options to this parameter, which might allow you to be a bit more specific, cf. [local_header_rewrite_clients docs on the postfix website](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_header_rewrite_clients)

Comment: This actually is not local mail.  This is a relay server for an external mail server.

Comment: By default, postfix will rewrite headers for clients it considers "local" but won't for "remote" clients, so long as "remote_header_rewrite_domain" is empty (the default).  If you're relaying mail from clients that match $mynetworks, those are considered local.  Is that the case?

Comment: Ok, yes it is relaying from clients that match $mynetworks.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this because it could save someone a few hours of messing around.

Also check that postfix is actually receiving the correct FROM header in the first place.  I use ssmtp to send mails throgh postfix and it was actually ssmtp which was overriding the FROM header.  I needed to set

```
FromLineOverride=YES
```

in the ssmtp.conf file to stop it overriding the from address.